# AvolonDock find all Layouts

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I'm trying to figure out how to use AvalonDock.
I'm not limited to MVVM and quite happy to make the following work with code-behind WPF.

I have the following Method which opens a new AvalonDock `LayoutDocument` and adds a WPF user control to it.

Before opening a new `LayoutDocument`, the Method checks that the title of the new  `LayoutDocument` doesn't already exist in `LayoutDocumentPane`.

This almost seems to work well.

The problem is that if the `LayoutDocument` being opened already exists and has been un-anchored from `LayoutDocumentPane` then it no longer exists in  `LayoutDocumentPane`.

How can I search for all `LayoutDocument` regardless of where they are anchored?

Method as follows:

```
private void OpenWindow(string title, System.Windows.Controls.UserControl userControl)
    {
        var firstDocumentPane = dockManager.Layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocumentPane>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstDocumentPane != null)
        {
            bool addChild = true;
            foreach (LayoutDocument child in LayoutDocumentPane.Children)
            {
                if (child.Title == title)
                {
                    child.IsSelected = true;
                    addChild = false;
                }
            }
            if (addChild == true)
            {
                LayoutDocument doc = new LayoutDocument();
                doc.Title = title;
                doc.Content = userControl;
                doc.IsSelected = true;
                firstDocumentPane.Children.Add(doc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

The following will list all `LayoutDocument` documents in `dockManager`

```
var currentContentsList = dockManager.Layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutDocument>().ToArray();
```

then loop through as follows:

```
foreach (LayoutDocument child in currentContentsList)
        {
             child.IsActive = true;
        }
```